# Output layer of LSTM (many to many)

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, tf.keras

I want to use LSTM to predict Y (size = [batch_size, time_length=1, feature_dim=3]) from X (size = [batch_size, time_length=42, feature_dim=12]). The problem is using data (12 features) during past 42 days to predict 3 features in the future (one day). For the original data, I have X as (365days*7years, 12features) and Y as (365days*7years, 3features). So how can transform it into the data for LSTM? what is the ideal data size?

And for the model training, I write my model as follows:

```
def keras_lstm(dimensions,
           input_timesteps, input_features, 
           output_feature
           ):
sgd_method = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=dimensions['learning_rate'],
                 momentum = dimensions['momentum'], nesterov=False)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
for i in range(dimensions['num_dense_layers']):
    name = 'layer_dense_{0}'.format(i)
    if i == 0:
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units = dimensions['num_filters'],
                                       input_shape=(
                                               input_timesteps,
                                               input_features),
                                       activation=dimensions['activation'],
                                       dropout=dimensions['dropout_rate'],
                                       return_sequences=True,
                                       name=name
                                       ))
    elif i < (dimensions['num_dense_layers']-1) and i >0:
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units = dimensions['num_filters'],
                                       activation=dimensions['activation'],
                                       dropout=dimensions['dropout_rate'],
                                       return_sequences=True,
                                       name=name
                                       ))
    else:
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units = dimensions['num_filters'],
                                       activation=dimensions['activation'],
                                       dropout=dimensions['dropout_rate'],
                                       return_sequences=False,
                                       name=name
                                       ))


model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = output_feature,
                                activation='linear', 
                                name='output'
                                ))
print(model.summary())

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error,
              optimizer= sgd_method,#adam, #'rmsprop',
              metrics=['mae', 'acc'])

return model
```

So am I correct? I think my input layer and the shape for the input layer is correct. But for th e output layer 'output', I am not sure whether it is correct. Because when I debug the code, I found that its output is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ldjag.jpg)

It seems that the shape of predicted (prediction of test data) is wrong...it should be as the same as data_label (ground truth label during testing process. By the way, should the batch size of data_input and data_label be same to each other? (I think so...I will correct the data processing codes....
And I am curious about why predicted is all the same...

```
ipdb> predicted
array([[-0.8785006 ,  0.19570428,  0.16157854],
   [-0.8785006 ,  0.19570428,  0.16157854],
   [-0.8785006 ,  0.19570428,  0.16157854],
   ...,
   [-0.8785006 ,  0.19570428,  0.16157854],
   [-0.8785006 ,  0.19570428,  0.16157854],
   [-0.8785006 ,  0.19570428,  0.16157854]], dtype=float32)
```

Is there anyone who can help me? thanks a lot!